# How to run a binary executable file in linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, executable

I have a executable file and when I double-click it, it works OK. but when I use terminal and type `./paraview` it gives me this error message:

```
Segmentation fault(Core dumped)
```

How to run paraview in terminal?

Comment: try `sh paraview`

Comment: It didn't work and gives me the following error paraview: 1: paraview: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: Which version of Paraview are you using? Did you installed a pre-built binary from Kitware or did you build Paraview on your own? Could you also precise which Linux distribution and version you are using?

Comment: @jcgiret I use ParaView 5.5.0-RC2 64-bit on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @jcgiret I only downloaded it.

Comment: @eliassoltanie, so normally you should have uncompressed the tar.gz archive downloaded from the Paraview website. Do you type the `./paraview`command from the `PATH_TO_PARAVIEW_DIR/bin` directory?

Comment: @jcgiret yes I uncopressed the tar.gz and yes I do that command in the `PATH_TO_PARAVIEW_DIR/bin`

Comment: @eliassoltanie, when you said you double-click it, could you elaborate on that? What are you exactly doing? I assume that something may be wrong in your environment variables. Did you modify/overload them in your .bashrc file?

Comment: @jcgiret I open `PATH_TO_PARAVIEW_DIR/bin` and I double-click on paraview.  I don't see anything realted to paraview in my bash file.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever is going on here is specific to this paraview program and not especially related to the Linux shell.  I don't know exactly what you're double-clicking on, but it could be a shortcut that includes specific command-line arguments, a specific working directory, etc.  It could also be that the way you're running a terminal causes it to have different environment variables set or something.

At any rate, a program shouldn't just crash by segfaulting when it's run in a way it doesn't expect, so this would definitely count as a bug in paraview.

Answer (score 1):

To know more about what the program is doing and why failing you could use [strace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace). based on your distro you could install it by using: `apt-get install strace` or `yum install strace`

Then give a try to this:

```
strace -f ./paraview
```

The option `-f`  is to trace child processes, it will help to get more info and hopefully find the root cause of the problem.

Comment: I used strace but I don't understand the output. Could you please look at it and see if you understand what is going on?     [pid  4834] recvmsg(10, 0x7ffd1832a070, 0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
[pid  4834] recvmsg(10, 0x7ffd1832a070, 0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
[pid  4834] --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0} ---
[pid  4835] +++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises from some permission issues. You will notice that if you are in PATH_TO_PARAVIEW_DIR/bin , try

```
sudo PATH_TO_PARAVIEW_DIR/bin/paraview
```

This should work.